# How to use file input/output functions efficiently on large files (using limited size of memory)

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, file-io, memory-mapped-files

There is an algorithm I want to implement on C++, which includes many file i/o's. Although I have implemented similar things on smaller scales, this time I need to work on files of several GB's. I know that there are some new things I should be considering when the file size is greater than the available memory size, and I should also be concerned about to cost.

My plan is to **get allocated memory size** and use it to **read a predetermined portion** and **save the results on a txt file** for each pass. However, I will need to **read and modify the resultant txt file line by line after each pass** to update it, since the resultant txt file will be a linked list (byte blocks will correspond to nodes).

Is it efficient to keep results of those passes on a txt file and update it line by line for each pass? I would appreciate if you can let me know any change that can make the algorithm more efficient. I would also appreciate if you could write some short/quick examples since I never used file input output other than "read this entire file", "write this as entire file" type of commands.

Edit: 
Operating system is Linux and Mac OS.

There are many byte segments repeating inside a binary file and I want to sort the number of times some combinations repeat. For example if a binary file is 111111100000001110101010100000111, I will count the number of occurrence of some predetermined patterns such as 110111001010, 10101011 etc. and sort them. Minimum file size I expect is 1GB and maximum is around 10-20GB. I will look for approximately 1,000,000,000 patterns and I will sort them all. So I thought since I need to update the output file every time my buffer is full, I might as well make it a linked list and update the list (should be ~O(n)) to avoid making a quick sort(should be ~nlog(n)) at the end.

Comment: What sort of "efficient" are we looking for? The only real concern if file-size [or actually, the input data as stored in your program] is bigger than the memory is that you can't process the entire file at once. But no, I don't think writing a text file that contains a linked list is a particularly great idea. Why do you think your data needs to be a linked list in the file?

Comment: "I would also appreciate if you could write some short/quick examples since" ...I don't want to do the homework myself!?

Comment: `I never used file [IO] other than "read this entire file", "write this as entire file"` - have a look at `<<` and `>>` for streams, _memory mapping_ (cost may differ from read-only to read-write) and _database_ integration. I'd be surprised if random-access updates to a text file appeared best.

Comment: @MatsPetersson because I need to sort my result, but it has too many elements. So I thought a linked list might have reduced the complexity. Why is this a bad idea? Should instead run a separate pass for sorting?

Comment: @OE1 - What is the structure of your data, and on what part do you need to sort?

Comment: Right now, my comment is simply gut feel - rewriting the output and storing it as a linked list doesn't seem like a good idea in general. However, you haven't given us enough information to determine exactly what you are trying to do, what the data is, how you need to work the data, etc.

Comment: @WernerHenze This is not a homework, and I wanted to point out that I will probably not understand what you are talking about unless you specify the function name or method you suggest, just as greybeard did(thanks). I am not asking you to write anything for me, this is a long project and I am just asking if people have any experience to share by copy pasting a function/algorithm name which would indeed save me a lot of time since I am unfamiliar with concept. I would have done this for someone else for pleasure, if you wouldn't, you should not be here reading other peoples problems.

Comment: The problem with "copy and paste code" and such is that the devil is in the detail. What is the input, what is the output (how big is the output?), what you actually do with the input to produce the output, what OS and what storage is it being read from/written to will all matter to some degree. But as the question stands, I'd say using a linked list stored as a file is not a good idea.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Just added some more relevant details. I basically want to make sure I am using file related accesses the right way and the trick I will try at least makes some sort of sense. I understand that it is hard to estimate such things but I want to take your opinions into account before I decide on a particular approach.

Comment: @Danny_ds Just updated the question to provide more details. It is a binary file, and I am interested in some predetermined patterns it contain. I will be sorting number of times each pattern has occurred.

Comment: I would just keep a table of counts in memory - perhaps a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` with the pattern as key and in integer count. Read the input, when you find relevant pattern, update the count. Repeat until finished. If you need to do it faster, use `mmap` to map the file into memory, and treat it as a lump of memory with content, rather than reading from the file - this will be marginally faster, but not much, since once you get over a few megabytes, the disk read will be the limiting factor.

Comment: @OE1 - Using `mmap` and keeping a table with the counts would indeed be the most efficient way.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Wouldn't storing entire table of counts be too large for the RAM, since significant part of the memory will be consumed by file access?  Should I be limiting the size of this map and saving the intermediate results and clearing them from RAM each time map is full? Or is this not as significant as I am predicting? (I'm not sure what available RAM I will have at the user end, on average I think it would be 1GB)

Comment: But you are only reading the file once, so storing the file in memory isn't going to be important.

Comment: (This is not a chat: if there is basic information in addition to what already is in the question, keep editing it as you did with `I want [about 10⁹ pairs of (count (potentially ≥ 2³²), pattern)] sorted`. (You didn't exclude count 0.)) Just created _Counting massive pattern occurrences in file - 
contribute to a viable approach to a data mining task_ - [join](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99113/counting-massive-pattern-occurrences-in-file) or don't. Consider removing questionable tags (linked-list being my "favourite") and adding data-mining (probably _not_ bigdata).

Comment: Avoid `txt` formats for large data. Use something *block oriented* with good random access properties. `mmap` when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an efficient way to do this:

Open your source-file and access your data with `mmap()`. This way you are accessing the `OS disk-cahe` directly and you **eliminate copying the memory** from `kernel mode` to `user mode`. If your files are really big, it is best to use smaller `mmapp-ed views` to prevent the creation of large page-tables.

Depending on the number of distinct patterns you are using, you have the following options:

**If the number of patterns is small enough to fit in memory**:

- If the values are sparse: store them in a `map` with pattern/count pairs.
- If the values are somewhat continuous, store the counts in a `vector`, where the position is the value of your pattern, based on an offset if needed.

**If the number of patterns can get big**:

(you're talking about 1 billion patterns - depends on how unique they are), you could create a `mmap-ed outputfile` and store the counts there, but make sure that all the values (or pairs) are the same width, i.e. store everything in binary (you can use this just as you would use an array).

If most of the values are distinct, store them at the position of your pattern-value - for example, if pattern (32bit?) + count is 8 bytes, store them at position `pattern-value * 8` for quick access. In case there are large gaps in your pattern-values, but you want to avoid inserting an moving data, consider using a (temporary) [`sparse file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) to store the values directly at the right position.

If you only needed a count, you could store the counts (32bit) only, at their specific position, but if you need a sort you'll also need the pattern values somehow.

To sort them, I would prefer using [`radix sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it addresses all complexities I had in mind. In my case, I will need the mmap-ed outputfile. How small do you mean by smaller mmapp-ed views? Around what size would be best to read the file and write to output for each pass? I was thinking around 500Mb or 1Gb but I am not sure if you meant that by small views?

Comment: @OE1 - The size of those views doesn't matter that much here, because they will only be used once. But I would probably not go above 1GB, Even 50MB to 100MB could be ok. Just make sure to check if the views need to overlap for your datastructure (i.e. a certain pattern might be on the edge of your views) - (views should be aligned on 64KB, which is the allocation granularity - although I would have to chech for Linux/Mac).